# Split conditions into two columns in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

Does anyone knows how i can split an IF statement which is hosted in one cell? 
Example 
One cell contains:
IF Condition1 THEN Action1
so i want to:
FIRST CELL: IF Condition1
SECOND CELL: THEN Action1

Comment: Why isn't it possible to put the condition in the second cell?

Comment: i have thousand of if statements in the excel file column and i want to separate them. I try to use the "Text to Columns functions" but doing this way i can only separate if i have a specific character. I have instead an specific word "THEN"

Answer (score 0):

For an IF...THEN... condition in B4:

In C4:

```
=LEFT(B4,LEN(B4)-SEARCH("THEN",B4)-1)
```

In D4:

```
=MID(B4,SEARCH("THEN",B4),500)
```